# Как реализовать поиск в веб приложении?

Tags: c#, sql-server, elasticsearch

Хочу попробовать *прикрутить* поиск в небольшое корпоративное приложении:

в бд(mssql) данные хранятся в двух таблицах

`Tools(Id int, TypeId int, OrderCode nvarchar, VendorId int)`

`ToolParameterHistories(ToolId int, ToolParameterId int, BoolValue bit, DecimalValue decimal(18,2), IntValue int, StringValue string)`

Подскажите как правильно добавить информацию из бд в `elasticsearch`, для того что бы потом можно было искать инструмент по набору характеристик, т.е. что то типа следующего:

```
SELECT t.* FROM Tools t
JOIN (SELECT * FROM ToolParameterHistories tph WHERE tph.ToolParameterId = 4 AND (tph.DecimalValue >= 10 AND tph.DecimalValue <= 12)) D ON D.ToolId = t.Id
JOIN (SELECT * FROM ToolParameterHistories tph WHERE tph.ToolParameterId = 5 AND (tph.DecimalValue >= 6 AND tph.DecimalValue <= 6)) r ON r.ToolId = t.Id
```

P.S.
Пока еще толком не понимаю как лучше реализовать данную *хотелку*, поэтому буду премного благодарен за информацию как принято делать подобные вещи

P.S.S
Если elasticsearch не предназначен для такого, то не стесняйтесь говорите